# Mongoose find each from array input

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i am trying to search db using each value of input array and then make separate entry if not found.. else skip it..
for ex.

input from client

```js
Inputquery = { 'make':'Audi', 'years':[0, 3 , 4]}
var count = 0;
for(var i=0; i<Inputquery.years.length; i++){
  vehicleSchema.find({
    'make':Inputquery.make, 
    'year':Inputquery.years[i]
  }, function(err, responseData){
    if(responseData.length>0){
      count++;
    }else{
      var newVehicle = new vehicleSchema();
      newVehicle.make = Inputquery.make;
      newVehicle.year = Inputquery.years[i];
      newVehicle.save(function(err, responseData){
        if(err){
          throw;
        }
        if(responseData){
          count++;
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
//this executing before waiting for previous operation to finish
if(count== Inputquery.years.length){
  //success
}
```

Please help me with above problem and also
i want to know is there any other approach to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think that this might be a better approach:

```
let make = 'Audi';
let years = [10, 11, 22];
vehicleSchema.find({
    make: make,
    year: { $in: years }
}, (data) => {
    if(data.length !== years.length) {
        // we need to figure out which years are missing and add them to the db
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var current = data[i];
            years.splice(years.indexOf(current.year), 1);
        }
        let missing = years; // these are the missing attributes, now we just loop through them and add new ones like usual
    } else {
        // all is well, there are no missing entries
    }
});
```

If you have any questions, let me know!